# R developing a bioconductor package with TDD (RUnit)

Tags: r, package, runit

I am trying to follow the [BioConductor RUnit guidelines](http://www.bioconductor.org/developers/unitTesting-guidelines/#duringDevelopment).
I have followed the the minimal setup so I have:

`Suggests: RUnit, BiocGenerics` in DESCRIPTION

`BiocGenerics:::testPackage("MyPackage")` in MyPackage/tests/runTests.R

and some test_XXX.R files in `MyPackage/inst/unitTests/`

If I run a single test files with:

```
library(RUnit)
source("LIBRARY FILES")
source("MyPackage/inst/unitTests/test_getKeywordValue.R")
test_getKeywordValue()
```

The test run (and fails when need to fail), but if I run

```
R CMD check MyPackage
```

The command say:

```
* checking tests ...
  Running ‘runTests.R’
 OK
```

But don't run my tests in `MyPackage/inst/unitTests` directory...

What I missing?

```
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin9.8.0  
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
```

Comment: This was cross-posted to, and received replies on, the [Bioconductor devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/bioc-devel/2013-January/003991.html) mailing list.

Comment: yes was me, sorry for the cross posting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

Here is the story:

I my package I putted a .Rinstignore file with this line:

```
test/*
```

I was expecting glob-style matching (like .gitignore) but instead, as `RShowDoc("R-exts")` say:

*.Rinstignore does perl-style regular expression matching.*

So, my rule `test/*` was interpreted by R as:

```
Ignore all files starting with test followed by 0 or more '/'
```

(the part /* was interpreted as match zero or more / characters)

A quick check with `grep` show how this work:

```
grep("test/*", "inst/unitTests/test_bar.R",perl=TRUE)
[1] 1
```

Removing the line

```
test/*
```

from .Rinstignore solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the BioC guidelines on this but I have a number of CRAN packages which use the scheme first developed by Martin Maechler for some Rmetrics packages.

It is described in this [R Wiki post](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=developers%3arunit), and you could look at my variations of this in, say, RcppArmadillo or RcppGSL or some other packages.  The key is often a file `tests/doRUnit.R` which does the necessary pivoting to be run from sources, or from the installed package.